# LINQ selecting multiple items stored types

Tags: c#, linq

First of all, I apologize as I feel I should be able to find this via Google, but I just can't seem to, most likely because my search terms are too general (or I just don't know what to look for).

Given:

```
int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var selectedNumbers = from n in numbers
                      where n > 2
                      select n;
```

What is var, given that more than one element has been selected?

To clarify: What object type should I treat it as? It has more than one element which would imply a collection of some sort (and I'm guessing it's treated as an interface of a certain type...?) but I'm not sure honestly *what* so I can properly use it in code.

Alternatively (though I still wish to know the first part for simple curiosity's sake), is there a good way to convert it to a normal collection, such as a `List<int>`?

Comment: This sounds like homework....

Comment: It's not! I (sadly) am done with my only C# class. I'm coding this to automate a trading minigame for my D&D DM that he came up with, but would require an extreme ammount of effort if he did it via pen, paper, and calculator. I've heard about Linq, and so I'm trying to teach myself it (alongside the SOLID principles) as I code his minigame.

Comment: Oh, I **ass** out of **u** and **me** d that it was, sorry (hint, what the bold letters spell)

Comment: Hey, I completely understand why it'd sound like homework. However, it would be awesome if I could pass off some tabletop gaming as university credit.

Comment: I know how you feel, my friend and I are gonna make a game :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `IEnumerable<int>`. The following code is equivalent:

```
IEnumerable<int> selectedNumbers =
     from n in numbers
     where n > 2
     select n;
```

To convert to a list, call `ToList()`.

```
List<int> list = selectedNumbers.ToList();
```

You could also do both operations in one line:

```
List<int> list = numbers.Where(n => n > 2).ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't it an IQueryable instead of IEnumerable? Although they do tend to work with eachother, I've never really gotten the difference between the two when LINQ is involved.

Comment: A lot of answers very quickly! However this seems like the best one. Thank you, Mark; you dealt with both issues very cleanly and clearly.

Comment: @Flater No, it's not an `IQueryable`.  The source is an array, which implements `IEnumerable` and doesn't implement `IQueryable`.  If the source was a database context of some sort then it would likely implement `IQueryable`, and then that overload of `Where` would have been used.

Comment: Aha, I've learned something today, thanks for the explanation. +1 to you, good sir :-)

Answer (score 2):

Easy: `IEnumerable<int>`

You should actually be able to hover your mouse over the variable in Visual Studio and the tooltip will tell you what it's type is.

Comment: This applies to any use of `var`.

Answer (score 2):

*var* is IEnumerable since from, where and select are just syntax sugar for IEnumerable extension methods. Beware that if you enumerate the *selectedNumbers* enumerable it will apply the query over *numbers* on each enumeration. If you use the *ToList* method you'll get a list with the results of the query.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be `IEnumerable<int>`.

To convert to a list, just use the `ToList()` extension method on selectedNumbers.

```
List<int> listOfNumbers = selectedNumbers.ToList();
```